# svn checkout http:// not working

Tags: svn, svn-checkout

The svn server is behind a proxy server which itself is behind a firewall.
`svn co http://*/*` doesnt work
returns: `repository permanently moved; please relocate`
while
svn co `svn+ssh://*/*` works well within the local domain of the proxy server.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you use the correct URL with the http protocol? Be aware that the **web** access (e.g. provided by ViewVC) is different from the **svn** access...

If you can, you should verify also the configuration on the webserver.

This question on ServerFault can be helpful also: [Subversion error: Repository moved permanently to please relocate](https://serverfault.com/questions/128242/subversion-error-repository-moved-permanently-to-please-relocate)